# about EPG data in Android TV

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-tv

I'm now creating a EPG App for android TV so i need to access to channels data stored in "/data/data/com.android.providers.tv/databases/tv.db". i tryed to make a Database helper this is the code :

package com.example.test;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
 * Created by Ahmed on 18/07/2017.
 */

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String DB_PATH=null;
    private static String DB_NAME="tvls -";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null   , 10);
        this.myContext=context;
        this.DB_PATH="/data/data/com.android.providers.tv/databases";
        Log.e("Path 1",DB_PATH);
    }
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        Log.i("Database Existe ?",""+dbExist);
        if (dbExist){

        }else{
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (Exception e ) {
                throw new Error("Error coying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
        int length;
        while ((length=myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer,0,length);

        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try{
            String myPath= DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch (SQLiteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (checkDB !=null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;


    }
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    String myPath= DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDataBase!=null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
    }
    public Cursor query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy) {
        return myDataBase.query("channels", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

but it dose not connect to the tv.db and throws me this error:

> 07-18 23:16:01.970 5361-5361/com.example.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                   Process: com.example.test, PID: 5361
>                                                                   java.lang.Error: Error coying database
>                                                                       at com.example.test.DatabaseHelper.createDataBase(DatabaseHelper.java:44)
>                                                                       at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
>                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

PS: If there is any information on how to use TvProvider please Help I'm stuck.
All i need to do is to read list of channel and their programs list.

Comment: Closest guide I can find with regard to EPGs are found in [Viewing for TV Input Framework](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/#viewing). Not sure if this will help but there's a [Building TV Channels](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/tif/index.html) guide and a [sample android-tv code](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-sample-inputs) you can run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer about this question:
 you need to pass throw a contentResolver to get data and store the result query in a cursor.

```
cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(TvContractCompat.Channels.CONTENT_URI,
                Channel.PROJECTION,
                null,
                null,
                null);
 if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                Log.i(TAG,cursor.getCount()+"Chaines ont étaient mise à jour avec Succés");
                do {
                    channels.add(Channel.fromCursor(cursor));

                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

then, in order to get acces to epg data you need to put these lines in the manifest:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="com.android.providers.tv.permission.READ_EPG_DATA" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.providers.tv.permission.WRITE_EPG_DATA" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.providers.tv.permission.ACCESS_ALL_EPG_DATA"/>
```

if you install the app as a user app the app will get only the epg data that it create so in order to get all the epg data in the tv you need to install it as system app in the /system/priv-app folder.